# MySQL, grouping words and saving them to two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

Have three tables:

```
products (relevant columns: id, name)
wordgroups (relevant columns: id, wordgroup)
productwordgroups (relevant columns: wordgroupid, productid)
```

Now I would like to separate each products.name into wordgroups of 1-3 words like this:

```
name = "A B C D E" => 
wordgroups = "A", "A B", "A B C", "B", "B C", "B C D", "C", "C D", "C D E", etc.
```

These wordgroups must then be saved to the wordgroups.wordgroup if they don't exist in the table already.

Finally, the many-to-many relation between table products and table wordgroups must be saved to productwordgroups if the relation doesn't exist in the table already.

Guess this can be done with some nasty SQL query, but so far I haven't been able to trick MySQL into doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: To me it seems you want to replicate what fulltext index does.

Comment: It's not for performance. We need the wordgroups and productwordgroups tables for calculating various things.

Comment: Can you give me an example pls? Because based on what you have described so far, I cannot see the difference.

Comment: Maybe I don't get fulltext index properly. How can I use it to get the wordgroups of 1-3 words for each products.name?

Comment: Another problem is that the table often needs to be copied to a different server. As far as I know, a fulltext index will increase the size of the table a lot => it will take much longer to copy.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the second part of the problem for you, that is if you extract all the letters to separate rows for the given name.

The extracting will need to be done in a procedure.

My code, where letters is input table and letter is a column:

```
select * from letters
union all
select a.letter||' '||b.letter as letter from letters a,letters b 
where a.letter<b.letter
union all
select a.letter||' '||b.letter||' '||c.letter as letter from letters a,letters b,letters c 
where a.letter<b.letter and b.letter<c.letter
```

This is my input:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

This is my output:

```
A
B
C
D
E
A B
A C
A D
A E
B C
B D
B E
C D
C E
D E
A B C
A B D
A B E
A C D
A C E
A D E
B C D
B C E
B D E
C D E
```

Comment: For the 2nd/3rd select, I just get a lot of rows where letter = 0. What is ".letter" and "||" supposed to do?

Comment: The script joins the table "letters" to itself - for the script to recognise which column "letter" belongs to which table "letters" I use acronyms a,b and c. The "||" means concatenate strings, in SQL server there is probably a different function. I concatenate letter from one table with "space" and letter from another table.